# nativescript axios - where can i see my XHR-Requests in debug-mode

Tags: vue.js, debugging, axios, nativescript

i created a app with **"tns create "**. I run the app in debug mode with **"tns debug ios"**. I integrated **axios**
in my project.

Where can i see the **XHR GET-Request-Response** ? There is nothing in console and nothing in the terminal-output. Simuator in running ok. **"devtools://devtools/bundled/inspector.html?experiments=true&ws=localhost:41000"** is running ok. The code is working fine in another vue-project.

Comment: Did you try restarting the dev tools window? Does other tabs show up properly, elements etc.,?

Comment: Yes i did restart. Other elements are shown. I removed axios from the project and used. "http". But no XHR GET-Request is shown in console or network in devtools.

Comment: Are you sure you are actually hitting GET, it should have displayed at least on console. Can you share some code?

Comment: Problem is solved, i used http now. Is running fine now. THX for help.